# ComboBox in Excel to return value, not index

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a range of duplicate dates in Sheet1!$A:$A. These I add as unique items to a combo box(cb) with VBA. Unfortunately, when I select an item (date in the cb) the index of the item is then returned into the linked cell.
Is there a way to return the date instead of the index, or fill the cb as item pairs (date , date)?

```
     A         B     C    ____D_________
1   date      val1 val2  |03/09/2015 |V |
2 03/08/2015   13   2.4  |          __|_ |
3 03/08/2015   17   4.6
4 03/08/2015   11   2.5
5 03/09/2015    9   1.5
6 03/10/2015    4   3.2
7 03/10/2015   12   3.4
```

in the example above, my cb would return 2 in D1 (which is the underlying linked cell), but I would like the date to be returned. Is there a "simple" way to accomplish this?

This does not seem to work:

```
With wsSheet2.Shapes("DatePick").ControlFormat
  .RemoveAllItems
  For Each vaItem In ncData
    .AddItem vaItem, vaItem  '<--- add an item pair
  Next vaItem
End With
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to populate the combobox, and the code that returns the '2'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub TransferValue()
    Dim dd As DropDown, linkedcell As String
    linkedcell = Sheet1.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.linkedcell
    Set dd = Sheet1.Shapes("Drop Down 1").OLEFormat.Object
    Sheet1.Range(linkedcell) = dd.List(dd.Value)
End Sub
```

I assumed you are using `Form Control` since you have a `LinkedCell`.
So this basically gets the `LinkedCell` address so you can use the same address for output.
Then you grab the value of the `ComboBox` or `DropDown Object` and pass it to the `LinkedCell` address. You just need to assign this *Macro* to your ComboBox. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the "cell link" in the Format Control options to `D1`, then in cell `D2` put:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,D1+1)
```

Comment: Just noticed you want the date in `D1`. Maybe this isn't exactly what you want but perhaps it will point you in the right direction.